# POB? Word that is ungrammatical to start a sentence?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have 3 out of 4 close votes for POB on something that is not POB. There's an answer, a real one, that has real English rules that should be attached. I want to know ... whose opinion would it be that determines non-grammatical answer?

This isn't "what's your favorite color" or "Which is the right word to use here?" This is ... if there's an answer, prove it. If it's POB that there isn't an answer (or that there is one?), I'm rather confused what I'm asking experts for.

[The question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222460/please-find-a-word-that-it-is-not-grammatically-correct-to-begin-a-sentence-or-q).

Comment: What is POB? <filler characters>

Comment: Primarily Opinion Based.

Comment: It's a fun question, as attested to by all the comments and the people who commented (a lot of fun was had by all, including me, who voted to close it). But, really, it *is* POB. Our *job*, so to speak, isn't to prove you wrong or right. The fact that you chose an answer doesn't mean it's *right*. It only means that someone thought of an acceptable answer. There are probably a hundred more.

Comment: If you're confused what you're asking about, how about the rest of us?!

Comment: @AndrewLeach What an awesome compliment. Thank you.

Comment: Where's the link to the question?!?

Comment: I somehow, I don't know how, managed to close it by accident. I have voted to reopen in recompense.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think [Please find a word that it is not grammatically correct to begin a sentence or question?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/222460/39720) is Primarily Opinion Based.
But one reading of the first two sentences

> Multiple questions herein ask "Is it grammatically correct to begin a sentence or question with X?"
>
> So, I'm definitively asking, are there any words for which it is absolutely not grammatically correct to begin a sentence with?

which motivate the rest of the post, makes it seem like it is.

I think the reading is meant to be:

> I've seen many questions asking "Is it grammatically correct to begin a sentence or question with X?"
>
> But I haven't seen one asking it the other way around: "Is there some word Y that cannot start a grammatically correct and non-trivial sentence?"
>
> *Description/examples of trivial cases*

But my first reading was:

> Many questions about *X* are asked.
>
> This question about *Not X* is meant to be used as a link to aid answering those questions:
> 'If *X* is not posted as an answer to this question, then your answer is *yes*.'

With this reading, I think the question *would* be close-worthy, because it appeals for not only a list but a complete one at that.
(I think the word *definitively* is what set me onto this interpretation.
Whenever I see that word, it's usually in the phrase "definitive list.")
This muddied the intention of the question for me, because it looked like you were asking for a list, when your next sentence explicitly says you weren't.

That aside, the question looks good to me.
I agree that [it looks like a trivia question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222460/please-find-a-word-that-it-is-not-grammatically-correct-to-begin-a-sentence-or-q#comment473866_222460), but I don't think we've decided yet on whether or not they should be kept or closed (and if closed, under what close-reason): [Acceptability of trivia questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6535/39720).

But if it came down to that, this question is interesting enough to me that it seems it would be a better candidate for [migration](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6536/39720) than closing.

Comment: More or less, though, the original question I posed was intended at first to be a reference question. But more of the kind of answer of "Not really, as any word can begin a sentence." instead of an exhaustive list of "allowed beginners".